# Kernal analysis R code to get 50 and 95% occupancy

Tags: r, kernel-density

[image: Sample of MyData used in the script][image: Resulting Shapefile from the script]I got a script from [Making 95% Volume Contour on ArcMap without Hawth's Tools or GME?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301368/making-95-volume-contour-on-arcmap-without-hawths-tools-or-gme). Since I am a novice to R, I tailored the code (below attached pic) and have successfully to some extent put this together but now I am stuck since the results are not quite what I would like to see. What code do I need to add to this so I can get home ranges in a Kernel analysis at 50% and 95% occupancy? The shapefile here doesn't show contours like I would like as in image.

[image: Kernel Density representation]

```
library(sp)
library(adehabitatHR)
library(raster)

# read in a .csv which contains lat and long for your data points
mydata <- read.csv("D:/Bats/mydata.csv", header = TRUE)
dput(head(mydata))

# create spatial points object
datapoints<-SpatialPoints(cbind(mydata$lat,mydata$lon))

kud <- kernelUD(datapoints, h="href", grid = 500 ) #kernel density utilization distribution (h=smoothing factor)

homerange95<-getverticeshr(kud, percent= 50, 95) #convert into vector object, use 50, 95 for quartic kernel

# set coordinates and write to shapefile which can be projected in ArcGIS

Coord<-homerange95
proj4string(Coord)<- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellips=WGS84")

raster::shapefile(Coord, "D:/Bats/homerange95_new.shp")
```

Comment: What does the code do? We don't have your data and the maps you've shown don't come from this code, so what have you done? Can you create and example with sample data we can all use? Have you read and understood the help pages for the functions you've used? Which function returns the information for the output you want to show?

Comment: I am so sorry for the incomplete info. Will add more info in. -Prabha

Comment: 1) The code reads the lat/lon from a file and creates a spatial points object with the lat/lon cols, runs Kernel Density Estimation and writes the resulting raster to a shapefile that was opened in Pro. 2) Sample of the mydata used in the script is provided 3) map in Pro showing resulting shapefile is shown 4) Yes, I read and understood all the functions I used in the script. I would like to see contours defined in the raster output which I don't know how to code in R to do that here. Please advice,

Comment: Can you illustrate your problem using example data, perhaps there's something included in the adehabitat packages, so that we can answer this without having to make up data ourselves.

Comment: Sorry I am not following you. I included the actual data i used, not all of it but a few lines. It is the png of the excel sheet. It is pretty straightforward dataset- lat/lons for each position of the bat. Do you want me to attach the excel sheet of the data here? I was only able to "add pictures" not actual files

Comment: This looks wrong: `homerange95<-getverticeshr(kud, percent= 50, 95)` - are you expecting this to compute contours for 50% and 95%?

Comment: oh I see.. Yes I was hoping for that but I could tell the resulting shapefile looks incorrect. Thank you for catching it, but I am not R savvy to know better way of writing it :(

Comment: You can only do one percentage contour at a time (read the help) so can you make two objects, one with percent=50 and one with percent=95? Also, no need to save to shapefile to just plot them, they are spatial objects.

Comment: ok, will give that a try. Thank you - Prabha

Comment: Thank u for your suggestions, I was able to get the contours and create a shapefile as well. Will post the code if it would helps others in the Answer section. Thank you -Prabha

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I eventually was able to get it to work for my project, jic it can help someone else:

```
library(sp)
library(adehabitatHR)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

# read in a .csv which contains lat and long for your data points

mydata <- read.csv("D:/Bats/mydata.csv", header = TRUE) 

# create spatial points object

datapoints<-SpatialPoints(cbind(mydata$lat,mydata$lon)) 

kud <- kernelUD(datapoints, h="href", grid = 5000 ) #kernel density utilization distribution (h=smoothing factor)

image(kud)

hr50<-getverticeshr(kud, percent= 50,unout = "m2") #convert into vector object, use 50 for quartic kernel

hr95<-getverticeshr(kud, percent= 95,unout = "m2") #convert into vector object, use 95 for quartic kernel

# Convert to data frames for plotting
hr50df <- fortify (hr50)
hr95df <- fortify (hr95)

# Plot with ggplot2
ggplot () +
  geom_polygon (data = hr95df, aes (x = long, y = lat, fill = id, group = group), alpha = 0.5, color = "black", size = 0.5) +
  geom_polygon (data = hr50df, aes (x = long, y = lat, fill = id, group = group), alpha = 0.8, color = "black", size = 0.5) +
  coord_equal () +
  theme_void ()

overwrite=TRUE 

# set coordinates and write to shapfile which can be projected in ArcGIS
WGScoor1<- hr50
proj4string(WGScoor1)<- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellips=WGS84")
raster::shapefile(WGScoor1, "D:/Bats/homerange50_new.shp")

WGScoor2<- hr95
proj4string(WGScoor2)<- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellips=WGS84")
raster::shapefile(WGScoor2, "D:/Bats/homerange95_new.shp")
```